# Override disabled style on v-btn

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I'm trying to override innate vuetify style for the disabled state of my buttons but I can't find the right style / classes / terms.

Here is my CSS :

```
.contained-btn {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: blue !important;
  border-radius: 4px !important;
}

.contained-btn:disabled {
  background-color: #DDE5ED !important;
  color: black !important;
}

.theme--light.v-btn.v-btn--disabled:not(.v-btn--flat):not(.v-btn--text):not(.v-btn-outlined):not(.contained-btn) {
  background-color: unset !important;
  border-color: unset !important;
}

.theme--light.v-btn.v-btn--disabled.contained-btn:not(.v-btn--flat):not(.v-btn--text):not(.v-btn-outlined) {
  background-color: revert !important;
}
```

The background-color doesn't work except if I uncheck those 2 styles in my developer tool :

[image]

For the color I have to uncheck this too :

[image]

How can I traduce this "uncheck" in my CSS please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution by adding this style :

```
.v-btn.v-btn--disabled.contained-btn:not(.v-btn--flat):not(.v-btn--text):not(.v-btn-outlined) {
  background-color: #DDE5ED !important;
  color: black !important;
}
```

Instead of :

```
.theme--light.v-btn.v-btn--disabled.contained-btn:not(.v-btn--flat):not(.v-btn--text):not(.v-btn-outlined) {
  background-color: revert !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For everybody using Vuetify 3, you can use css variables like this:

```
html body .v-theme--light {
    --v-disabled-opacity: 1;
}
```

Obviously, if you are using the dark theme you should do this:

```
html body .v-theme--dark {
    --v-disabled-opacity: 1;
}
```

I'm not sure if this works for vuetify 2